# I do commit locally , and all is well , but when I push on GitHub, the commit it comes empty and files are have no changes. Why?

Tags: git, github

Locally, there have commited files. But on GitHub files are without changes. Why? How i can push my local changes on GitHub? Thank you

i do this:

```
git clone <myrepo>
cd <myrepo>
git init
git add .
git commit -m <commit>
git push origin master
```

Comment: This question is not precise enough to be responded correctly. You need to show at least an example of local commit which is not updated on gitHub and the commands you type to push and commit.

Comment: You issue could also be a matter of branches. Are you working on master branch?

Comment: In master. I see my commit on GitHub, but files are have no any changes

Comment: That would mean your commit was empty. Git normally warns about empty commits so they normally do not happen unwanted. Most likely you're confusing the file states? Can you see the commit for real on Github? If yes, please provide reference to the commit on Github. Like others have commented your question has too little information to give a good answer already.

Comment: i do this:
`git diff origin`
and
`git log`
and i see, that i have changes locally

Comment: What does git say when you do the `push`?

Comment: Thanks to all! It is ok. it was my inattention. I am sorry for disturb

Answer (score 1):

I commented the sequence of commands you typed. Maybe that can help you understand your issue...

```
git clone <myrepo>
cd <myrepo>
# You don't need to do git init for a cloned repository.
git init
# Have you changed anything on your local file before git add .? Otherwise you commit will be empty.
git add .
git commit -m <commit>
git push origin master
```

You should also look at your history (gitk) before pushing. That will show you the lists of commits you've done and the changes they include.

Comment: i do this:
`git diff origin`
and
`git log`
and i see, that i have changes locally. Localy is normal

Answer (score 0):

You could look into creating a `Pull Request` and merging the code pushed onto the `master`. Post which you would be able to see the changes.